# How to delete current region clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code with a link that should delete the region it belongs to :

```
<a href="javascript:function() { $(this).closest(".DatesSelection").remove(); };">
  <div class="CloseButton">
    Close
  </div>
</a>
```

The button is generated but when I click it, I have the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

How can I resolve that?

Comment: You can do it as `<a onclick="$(this).closest(".DatesSelection").remove();">` instead of `<a href="javascript:function() { $(this).closest(".DatesSelection").remove(); };">`

Comment: Watch your quotation. Isn't the quote started with the double quotation mark here `href="` broken earlier than you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the function definition within the `href` attribute and the use of quotes. To fix this, remove the `function()` around your logic, use `onclick` for an inline handler and use separate quotes to delimit the atttribute value and the selector string:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.DatesSelection').remove();">
```

***However***, a much better approach entirely would be use unobtrusive event handlers instead of stuffing inline JS code in to `href` (where it should never be) or `on*` event attributes (which are now massively outdated), like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.DatesSelection a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".DatesSelection").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DatesSelection">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="CloseButton">
      Close
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="DatesSelection">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="CloseButton">
      Close
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="DatesSelection">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="CloseButton">
      Close
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use event delegation, set click event listener on some parent container and check whether the source of the event is the corresponding anchor.

- `event.target.tagName === 'A'` checks if the event was triggered by `a` element
- `event.target.parentNode.className === 'DatesSelection'` checks whether the parent of the element which triggered the event has class `DatesSelection`
- if both conditions are met then remove the parent element of the one that has triggered the event

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.parentNode.className === 'DatesSelection') {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="DatesSelection">
  <a href="#"> Close </a>
</div>

<div class="DatesSelection">
  <a href="#"> Close </a>
</div>
```